# fs.readFileSync is not a function in Cypress using a parse-pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg9eI.png) I'm having the error in the image above when trying to use node's "readFileSync" function in its native package parse-pdf
my code in github: https://github.com/lucasbeninca/testing-pdf-with-cypress

I cannot find a reason why it is not recognized by cypress

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are importing the module, which is meant for node, inside of a Cypress *test* which actually executes in the browser where node APIs are not available.

Cypress does have a node backend though, and the way to get around your problem is register handlers in the cypress config (which is executed in node) and call those using [cy.task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task).

Actually it looks like you started to do this, but then you imported `cypress/scripts/readPdf.js` in your test *as well*. The var `readPdf` isn't used there and is not needed.

Fix is simply to remove it and rely on your task call, which will execute the task you registered inside of node:

```
describe('testing-pdf-with-cypress', function() {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('../app/index.html');
  });

  it('downloads a simple PDF file', () => {
    cy.contains('simple.pdf')
        .click();

    cy.readFile('cypress/downloads/simple.pdf', 'utf8');
    cy.task('readPdf', 'cypress/downloads/simple.pdf');
  });

  it('downloads a complex PDF file', () => {
    cy.contains('complex.pdf')
        .click();

    cy.readFile('cypress/downloads/complex.pdf');
    cy.task('readPdf', 'cypress/downloads/complex.pdf');
  });
});
```