# Can pg (Postgres Node Package) Be Used With Cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I'm trying to use the `pg` module to do cleanup [before](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#State-reset-should-go-before-each-test) Cypress tests, but I'm running into a problem.

When I try to use `pg` in Cypress, like so ...

```
import { Client } from 'pg';

describe('Some Test Suite', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const connectionString = 'postgres://someuser@localhost:5432/somedatabase';

        // Next line causes: TypeError: CloudflareSocket is not a constructor
        const client = new Client({ connectionString });
        await client.query('SELECT NOW()');
```

I get an error:

> index-0d246d3b.js:106516 TypeError: CloudflareSocket is not a constructor

It's coming from this code inside `Stream.js`, inside the `pg` package:

```
module.exports.getStream = function getStream(ssl) {
  const net = require('net')
  if (typeof net.Socket === 'function') {
    return new net.Socket()
  } else {
    const { CloudflareSocket } = require('pg-cloudflare')
    return new CloudflareSocket(ssl)
  }
}
```

From what I've read online, `net.Socket` should exist (and be a function) as long as its run on the server-side, so I should be using `net.Socket()`, not `CloudflareSocket`.  By getting this error my code is (evidently?) [being run in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599069/node-js-net-socket-is-not-a-constructor).

However, I thought Cypress code was run in Node, not the browser, so I'm not sure what I'm getting this error, or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77012343/fs-readfilesync-is-not-a-function-in-cypress-using-a-parse-pdf

Comment: If you can put that in the form of an answer I would happily accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) is a node package

> node-postgres is a collection of **node.js modules** for interfacing with your PostgreSQL database

You will have to shift your code out of the browser and into a [Cypress task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task), in order to query the database.

This is a simple example.

In **cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const { Client } = require('pg')

const pgConfig = {
  user: "admin",
  password: "password",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "dbname",
  ssl: false,
  port: 5432
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("task", {
        async queryDb(queryString){
          const client = new Client(pgConfig)
          await client.connect()
          const res = await client.query(queryString)
          await client.end()
          return res.rows;
        }
      })
    },
  },
})
```

**Mods to the test**

You don't need `async` to call a task, Cypress awaits a promise returned from the task to resolve before continuing.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.task('queryDb', 'SELECT NOW()').then(result => {
    ...
```